# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf 'notes.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it

Tags: python, django

I get this error in the root directory, not in an app. The code in urls.py of this root directory is:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('write_notes.urls'))    # `write_notes` is the name of my app.
]
```

Code in write_notes.urls:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index-page'),
    path('/signup', views.SignupView.as_view(), name='signup-page'),
    path('/note', views.WriteNoteView.as_view(), name='write-note-page')
]
```

What is the error and how do I fix it?

Comment: Can you show `write_notes.urls`

Comment: the error message is about "notes.urls" not about "write_notes.urls" - where is notes.urls used in your apps?

Comment: The name of the root directory is 'notes', and I have shared the code of 'notes.urls'. I have not used 'notes.urls' anywhere in my app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error happened to me too, and the reason for it was the use of reverse in one of my classes, which was used in urlpatterns.
Therefore, if you have used reverse in one of the SignupView and WriteNoteView classes, it is most likely the reason for the error. I solved the problem by converting reverse("pathname ") to absolute path as bellow:

```
login_url = reverse('login')
```

changed to:

```
login_url ='accounts/login'
```

Although reverse('pathname') is highly recommonded and result of two above code is same, but i don't know why this solve the error. I hope this help you

Comment: check the spellling of 'urlpatterns' in the child module. I ecountered this problem when i use the urlpattterns instead of urlpatterns

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are missing the following code to add in notes.urls

```
from django.urls.resolvers import URLPattern //*

urlpatterns = [

]
```